# How do I upgrade the MYSQL database from Craft 2 to Craft 3 on GoDaddy

Tags: craft3, craft2, mysql

How do I upgrade my MySQL DB for a Craft 2 site to Craft 3. I don't have access to the SSH server or use of Composer, so I have to move files via FTP and do everything manually.

My client is on GoDaddy, and need to resolve this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:

1. Get the Craft 2 site running locally.
2. Perform the upgrade to Craft 3 locally according to the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html
3. Test and make sure everything works as you'd expect.
4. Upload all fo the files to your web server via FTP (including composer.json, composer.lock, the vendor folder, etc.).
5. Once load, load the Craft control panel, you'll be prompted to let Craft update the database.
6. Let Craft update the database.
7. Done!

Specifics may vary depending on the site and your actual requirements.